# Slug regenerating it self

Tags: propel, slug

I'm using the `sluggable` behavior within Propel to work alongside my CMS/Framework.

Weird thing is, if you change something else on the page, other than the slug, the slug will automatically regenerate using what appears to be the values of the parent element, i.e.

from `/slug` to `id-3-parentid-2-keywords-null-templateid-1-publishdate-null-slug-slug-sortablerank-2-createdat-null-updatedat-null-pagei18ns-pagei18n_0-id-3-locale-en_gb-title-tsadf-description-null-content-p-ssadf-p-page-recursion-pagei18n_1-id-3-locale-fr_fr-title-a` which is rather odd.

The only solution I've found so far, is to simply call setSlug to a random value and then set the correct value afterwards.

```
$page->setSlug('x');
$page->setSlug($this->request->post->get('slug'));
```

and my schema:

```
<table name="page" phpName="Page">
    <!-- Columns -->
    <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
    <column name="parent_id" type="integer" required="false" />
    <column name="title" type="varchar" size="255" required="true" />
    <column name="description" type="varchar" size="255" required="false" />
    <column name="keywords" type="varchar" size="255" required="false" />
    <column name="content" type="longvarchar" required="false" />
    <column name="template_id" type="integer" required="false" />
    <column name="publish_date" type="date" required="false" />
    <!-- Behaviors -->
    <behavior name="i18n">
        <parameter name="i18n_columns" value="title, description, content" />
        <parameter name="default_locale" value="en_GB" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="sluggable">
        <parameter name="permanent" value="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="sortable" />
    <behavior name="timestampable" />
    <!-- Foreign Keys -->
    <foreign-key foreignTable="page_template">
        <reference local="template_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="page">
        <reference local="parent_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
</table>
```

Note: I've tried with and without the permanent param.

Any idea's anyone?

Comment: This is with propel 2?

Comment: Hi @Leentje, it certainly is.

Comment: Please check http://propelorm.org/documentation/behaviors/sluggable.html
You want to set certain attributes for the sluggable behavior. Right now it seems it doesn't know which field to use as a reference for creating a slug (because you haven't defined this)

Comment: You want something like this:

   `<behavior name="sluggable">  
    <parameter name="slug_column" value="slug" />  
    <parameter name="slug_pattern" value="{Title}" />  
    <parameter name="replace_pattern" value="/[^\w]+/u" />  
    <parameter name="replacement" value="-" />  
    <parameter name="separator" value="-" />  
    <parameter name="permanent" value="true" />  
    </behavior>`